# HTML5 Canvas FPS drops when rendering another canvas as an image using drawImage() at a specific width & height

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So I have run into a very strange problem while using the HTML5 Canvas API. I'm attempting to create a game and the problem occurs because I'm drawing different canvases (using drawImage()) onto the main canvas. The other canvases has had graphics drawn on them and then I am simply drawing those canvases onto the main one. The problem is that at very specific widths and heights (coming close to the width and height of the main canvas) the fps suddenly drops by about 20-30. And this happens when only drawing one of those big canvases onto the main one. I thought the performance drop might've been attributed to drawing such a big canvas with graphics on them, so I emptied the canvases and was basically drawing an "empty" canvas onto the main canvas. Even so, the performance dropped. What's even more stange is that when I subtract just ONE pixel from either the width or height of the big canvas the fps goes back to 60! The widths and heights that this has occurred (there are probably more sets) are:

W: 1797
H: 891

W: 2026
H: 790

So for example for the first set, if you were to draw a canvas with those measurements (EVEN AN EMPTY ONE) you would get 30-40 fps. Yet if you were to draw a canvas with those one of the measurements subtracted by one (i.e. W: 1796, H: 891) then it would go  back to 60 fps.

What I find even more strange is that this happens on only Chrome. I have tried it on Internet Explorer and Safari and I can draw significantly bigger canvases (i.e. far bigger than even the main canvas) and still get 60 fps. I'm sorry for not being able to list the code because it would require me to post a significantly large piece of code (the code is intertwined in multiple files). Could somebody elaborate on why this is happening? Thank you!

EDIT: This also happens if I draw only a clipped version of the big canvas using the other version of drawImage(). So it doesn't even have to do with rendering the actual number of pixels...which I find extremely strange.

EDIT 2: So I have run some tests and turns out it has nothing to do with the rendering but rather the memory usage because of the fact that I have an array that's holding 25 of these big canvases. I created a fiddle to benchmark:

https://jsfiddle.net/eu3zoc4f/3/

HTML:

```
<body>
     <canvas id="canvas" style="display: block;"></canvas>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var timer = {
  startedAt: null,
  stoppedAt: null,
  start: function() {
    this.stoppedAt = null;
    this.startedAt = new Date();
  },
  stop: function() {
    this.stoppedAt = new Date();
  },
  getTime: function() {
    if (!this.stoppedAt) this.stop();

    return this.stoppedAt.getTime() - this.startedAt.getTime();
  }
};


var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
body[0].style.width = screen.availWidth + "px";

document.getElementById("canvas").width = window.innerWidth;
document.getElementById("canvas").height = window.innerHeight;


var context = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

var TESTING_1 = [];
for (var c = 0; c < 25; c++) {
  TESTING_1[c] = document.createElement('canvas');
  TESTING_1[c].width = 2000;
  TESTING_1[c].height = 1200;
  TESTING_1[c].getContext('2d').fillStyle = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';
  TESTING_1[c].getContext('2d').fillRect(0, 0, 1900, 897);

}

function main() {


  timer.start();
  context.drawImage(TESTING_1[0], 0, 0);

  context.fillStyle = "blue";
  context.font = "20px Arial";
  context.fillText(timer.getTime(), 100, 100);

}


main();
```

If you change the "25" number that's in the for loop to a lower number you will get much faster results. So the problem now is why is this happening only in Chrome and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I read that and it says that the width and height have to be a power of 2 or the context will stretch it to be that. The problem is that in my situation I only have to take away one pixel from the specific widths and heights and the fps goes back to 60. Even if the results of that subtraction are not a power of 2 (i.e. W: 1796, H: 891). Also, if this were the case, then it should've been a problem on ALL browsers but it only happens on Chrome (maybe Firefox I havn't tried that). Thank you for your input though.

Comment: You have 25 canvas that are 2000 by 1200, the minimum memory for all that is 9.6Mb each for a total of 240Mb.  The cause of the slow down if the browser moving images onto the GPU from main memory. This blocks rendering and the transfer speeds are nowhere near the GPU bus speeds. Ensure you have no other tabs or instances of the browser up and running. To see GPU memory (chrome) "shift + esc" right click and add GPU memory. This will list all usage. There is anoth chrome page that may help, I will find it and add a comment.

Comment: For more info on your GPU goto `chrome://gpu` in the address bar, you may also want to try `chrome://flags` to mess with the GPU setting (WARNING can cause bad things to happen). You are pushing the limits of the system. All you can do is reduce memory usage

Comment: Even though the canvases are big, how come memory is still being taken up when they are empty and no pixels have been drawn on them? Also, you say that I'm using 240Mb. However, using the following; https://gist.github.com/zensh/4975495 I was able to check the size of the object containing all the canvases and it said it was around 1 Kb...

Comment: When you create a canvas you create a memory buffer containing 4 bytes for every pixel, even if you do nothing to it. So a canvas that is 2000 by1200 needs when first created 2000 * 1200 * 4 bytes of free RAM, either on system RAM or GPU RAM (plus the API native code and drivers) so that is 9.6Mb + for a single image. No idea where you got 1kb from. A single empty object var obj = {} requires 8+ kb to exist. The simplest javascript context for a page (without any code) requires several megabytes to exist.

Comment: The GitHub linked function is completely incorrect. Use the browser's developers tools (hit f12) and profile your code and you will see that javascript if Very memory hungry (about the worst I know of).

Comment: Okay so I have tried to use the Task Manager to profile and it appears that the Javascript Memory section is only reading around 9.1 Mb... That's nowhere close to 240Mb. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: Hence the slow down. You need 240MB of GPU memory to store all the images so you can render at full speed. Without that memory available you are swapping memory, this is slow. When the system runs low it will even start to page memory from virtual (hard disk) RAM. You can not reduce the RAM each pixel requires (transparent or not) you must work within the bounds of what your system can handle

Comment: Okay thank you! One final question: How do I see how much TOTAL memory my application is using (i.e. to be able to then see all that 240+ Mb of memory)?

Comment: Also, if it's only the GPU's fault, then how come this only happens on chrome and not on other browsers?